# Can the proof of Lusin's theorem in Stein-Shakarchi Real Analysis be simplified?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

The following is Lusin's theorem (reminiscent of [Littlewood's second principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Littlewood%27s_three_principles_of_real_analysis)) and its proof in Stein-Shakarchi *Real Analysis* (page 27):

> [image]
>   [image]

Here $m$ is the Lebesgue measure on ${\bf R}^d$ and step functions are defined as

> [image]

My **question** concerns the second sentence in the proof:

> Since the $f_n$'s are all step functions, isn't it true that one can make $m(E_n)=0$ for all $n$? What's the point of using $m(E_n)<1/2^n$ instead? Am I missing something here?

Comment: If $m$ was the lebesgue measure on $(0,1)$ (let's say), then the discrete number of discontinuity points will give $\lambda(E_n)=0$. Here we cannot say such thing because the measure $m$ is general.

Comment: @anonymus Thanks for your comment. I have edited the question. The measure $m$ in this context should be the Lebesgue measure.